# Union subgroup implies that the group is one of the subgroups.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group and $H_1, H_2\leq G$ such that $H_1\cup H_2=G.$

How can I prove that either $G=H_1$ or $G=H_2$?

Comment: Suppose both were proper subgroups. Choose $g_i \in G\setminus H_i$, then ...

Comment: I'm confused - such that $H_1\cup H_2$ *what*?

Comment: Prove that $H_1 \cup H_2$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $H_1 \subset H_2$ or $H_2 \subset H_1$